# Would it take any sort of amendment to make DC a state?

Tags: united-states, constitution, statehood, washington-dc

To achieve statehood for DC, would an amendment to the Constitution need to be passed, or would it just work like a regular territory, i.e. only needing Congress to pass a law?

Answer (score 12):

Washington, DC could become a state with just a law, but its representation in the electoral college would not be able to increase properly with population due to the [twenty-third amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-third_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution):

> **Section 1.** The District constituting the seat of Government of the United States shall appoint in such manner as the Congress may direct:
>
> A number of electors of President and Vice President equal to the whole number of Senators and Representatives in Congress to which the District would be entitled if it were a State, but in no event more than the least populous State; they shall be in addition to those appointed by the States, but they shall be considered, for the purposes of the election of President and Vice President, to be electors appointed by a State; and they shall meet in the District and perform such duties as provided by the twelfth article of amendment.

So long as Washington, DC remains the seat of government of the US, it would be limited to the number of electors in the least populous state.  Unless of course this amendment were considered moot in the situation of statehood.  Presumably most of it would be rendered moot (otherwise the electoral college would get rather goofy with the DC electors being both in addition and part of those appointed by the states).  Perhaps that clause would as well.

It would be more reliable to repeal the twenty-third amendment in that circumstance.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'd think the amendment would still count, but it might not be considered a "District" so that could be weird.

Comment: Hm, so you're saying that a law could give DC 2 Senators and however many representatives as they'd deserve, but no matter how many representatives they had, they'd only have 3 electoral votes, unless the 23rd amendment was repealed

Comment: One option for DC statehood is for the majority of the city to become a new state, but federal properties such as the capitol and the Supreme Court would remain as the District. Presumably there is very little if any residential zoning on federal property (excluding the white house). Would this be a possible means of averting the 23rd amendment?

Comment: @DavidK: They would still have to "appoint [electors] in such manner as the Congress may direct", population or no population. But Congress could direct them to appoint electors who voluntarily abstain, one supposes.

Comment: Best would be to remove housing from the area just by the capital and incorporate the rest of DC back into Maryland.

Comment: I rather think that if DC became a state it would no longer be " the district constituting the seat of government" because it would become the state constituting the seat of government.

Comment: If Congress and Tennessee in their combined infinite wisdom decided, then Nashville could be the new federal district and Washington could be a state unlimited in electors:  https://politics.theonion.com/congress-threatens-to-leave-d-c-unless-new-capitol-is-1819566457

Comment: @DavidK Presumably if you did that without eliminating the 23rd, you would end up with a situation where the District would still have three electors, whose votes would be controlled by its residents—which, at that point, would constitute the residents of the White House, which obviously is problematic.

Comment: The people who live in the White House are not residents of Washington, DC.  Currently their residence for voting purposes is New York City.  This is typical.  While in reality, presidential families live in the White House, the legal fiction is maintained that they are still residents of wherever and just visiting DC.

Comment: "The District constituting the seat of Government of the United States shall appoint in such manner as the Congress may direct:" <- Once DC becomes a state, there is no longer a district constituting the seat of government, which appoints. At least, that's what my lay reading of this section suggests.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from the [23rd Amendment](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/amendmentxxiii) issues that have been mentioned in other answers, there are some additional parts of the Constitution that would cause me to argue that an amendment to the Constitution would indeed be required in order for D.C. to become a state (at least as long as it remained the seat of government.)

I would argue that [Article I, Section 8](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/articlei#section8) prevents the seat of government from being in any state. It says,

> The Congress shall have the power...
>
> To exercise exclusive legislation in all cases whatsoever, over such District (not exceeding ten miles square) as may, **by cession of particular states**, and the acceptance of Congress, become the seat of the government of the United States, and to exercise like authority over all places purchased by the consent of the legislature of the state in which the same shall be, for the erection of forts, magazines, arsenals, dockyards, and other needful buildings;--And
>
> To make all laws which shall be necessary and proper for carrying into execution the foregoing powers, and all other powers vested by this Constitution in the government of the United States, or in any department or officer thereof.

It seems pretty clear (to me, at least) that the intent here is that the seat of the government of the United States is to not be part of any state and that Congress shall have exclusive legislative control over it, unlike with the states.

Additionally, [Article IV, Section 4](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/articleiv#section4) says,

> The United States shall guarantee to every state in this union a republican form of government, and shall protect each of them against invasion; and on application of the legislature, or of the executive (when the legislature cannot be convened) against domestic violence.

The guarantee that every state would have a republican form of government necessitates that the state would have its own legislature. If D.C. were to become a state while remaining the seat of government, it could not simultaneously satisfy both this requirement and the above-listed requirement of Article 1, Section 8 that Congress have exclusive legislative control over the seat of government. Therefore, it would not be constitutional for D.C. to become a state while remaining the seat of government.

Of course, if Congress decided to move the government somewhere else - and one or more states agreed to cede that territory to the federal government for the creation of a new seat of government district - then D.C. could be admitted as a state without a further amendment to the Constitution once it was no longer the seat of government. Alternatively, Congress could choose to give the remainder of the District of Columbia back to Maryland after the seat of government was moved, just as [in 1847 Congress gave back the portion of the District that had been ceded by Virginia back to Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_of_Columbia_retrocession#Virginia_retrocession).

Yet another possibility would be for most of the remaining part of D.C. to be [returned to Maryland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_of_Columbia_retrocession#Proposed_Maryland_retrocession), while leaving only the federal lands around where the White House, Capitol, and Supreme Court reside in a federal seat of government district. This could be done without an amendment and has actually been proposed quite a few times over the years, including relatively recently. The only part of this that might require an amendment would be repealing the 23rd Amendment, so that the handful of people (the President and maybe a few others?) who still lived in the federal portion wouldn't have 3 electoral votes to themselves.

Comment: It would probably also be possible for today's DC to become a state with the "seat of government" shrinking somewhat as described.  Presidents have typically voted in home states, it's also possible that the "seat" could be shrunk to just the capitol, or maybe that and the west wing (but not the east), intervening parkland, supreme court, etc.

Comment: Historically the seat of government has not always been a separate, non-state district. Congress met in New York City for its first year, then passed legislation naming Philadelphia as a temporary capitol for 10 years after that while Washington, D.C. was under construction. So while the intent may be that the capitol be a district, it doesn't seem to be a constitutional requirement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Capitol#Background

Comment: I don't think the "republican form of government" clause necessarily contradicts the requirement that Congress have ultimate authority. The existing DC Council is already a quasi-state legislature, and could continue to operate in that role under hypothetical statehood. The Constitution doesn't say that Congress can't overrule states' republican governments, and to the contrary it's well-established that Congressional authority trumps the states in some areas. I'm not convinced this would be a reasonable system, but I don't see why it's not possible.

Comment: @ChrisBouchard The original intent of the cited portion of Article I, Section 8 seems to be that the seat of government would, in fact, be a federally-administered district separate from any of the states, though with the understanding that it would take some time for that to happen. Since the power to even select that district was granted to the Congress, it seems pretty clear that they understood that the government would have to meet _somewhere_ temporarily until the capitol district could be constructed.

Comment: @JustinLardinois Several portions of the Constitution separate powers between states and the federal government. Article I, Section 8's grant of complete legislative control of the seat of government district to Congress isn't really compatible with having it be part of an actual state. There is indeed a DC city council, but it was created by Congress and could be dissolved by Congress at any time should they wish to do so. The same is not true of a state legislature. No court has ruled on it to date, but my opinion would be that it would not meet the Article IV, Section 4 requirement.

Comment: @JustinLardinois Federal authority does trump state authority in some areas (specifically, the ones where federal authority is granted by the Constitution,) but the Congress certainly does _not_ have the complete legislative authority over any state that the Constitution grants it for the seat of government district.

Comment: @ChrisStratton True, but then you'd still have the 3 electors specified by the 23rd Amendment to figure out what to do with.

Comment: @reirab If the shrunken DC had no population, no one can vote for, or even be, an elector (congress determines DC's mechanism for selecting electors).  And since the required majority is of the electors *appointed* not those who *could be* it doesn't even cause a problem there.

Comment: @reirab I'm aware of the distinction between supremacy versus Congress's complete authority over DC versus; all I'm saying is that I don't think it's a total contradiction for hypothetical DC state. Also, it's not like we don't currenlty have different parts of the Constitution competing with each other; that's something the courts are perfectly capable of sorting out.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Wikipedia says elections were held in some Union-controlled Confederate states in 1864, but those electors were ultimately not counted. I have no idea what the legal basis for that was and of course it was during a war, but perhaps that could be precedent for ignoring electoral votes when it's impractical to count them.

Comment: It says "may, by cession of particular states," <- so this may also not happen. If DC is recognized as a state, there is no longer such a district which has become the seat of government etc. Although maybe the new state would make its own cessions.

Comment: @einpoklum No, we're way past the point of "may not happen" because it already did happen over 200 years ago. The intent of the Constitution was clear: the District, once created, was not to be part of any state. If they had wanted to just make it its own state, they could have done that just as easily, but that was very clearly contrary to the intent.

Comment: It is "very clear" to you, and after adding a statement that's not in the constitution. But I guess it's a question of whether this will be brought up before the Supreme Court, and what the court's interpretation will be.

Comment: @einpoklum There is no question about it; it is indeed very clearly their intent because they said so. No need to take my word for it. You can take [the word of the guy who wrote it](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/18th_century/fed43.asp), who described the arrangement of the capital not being located in a state to be an "indispensable necessity." (See bullet #2.)

Comment: @reirab: Yes, with that text it seems you're right. Perhaps the new state could, with its formation, also provide a micro-district to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: @einpoklum Or just follow the established precedent and give the residential areas that want to be part of a state back to Maryland, then repeal the 23rd. This has already been done in the past with the part of D.C. that was ceded by Virginia. They ended up deciding the feds didn't need it and just gave it back to Virginia. This is where Arlington, etc. is today.

Comment: @reirab: Hmm... actually, you might not even need to repeal the 23rd; if DC territory is returned except for a micro-district, perhaps the new state could be formed by splitting Maryland?

Comment: @einpoklum There would be no reason to form a new state. The land could just be given back to Maryland and remain a part of Maryland, as was done with Virginia. The residents would then have normal Congressional representation just like everyone else. Repealing the 23rd would only be necessary so that you wouldn't still have electoral votes assigned to the federal district where no one is supposed to be living, aside from some government officials (like the President.)

Comment: @reirab: The reason would be that the people in DC want to be a state, and Maryland would agree (if politics allow of course).

Comment: @einpoklum Lots of areas of other states (California especially comes to mind) would like to be their own states, too, but forming new states out of existing ones for political purposes generally sets a bad precedent and is, thus, generally avoided. So far, the only exception is that West Virginia was allowed to separate from Virginia when Virginia voted to leave the U.S. in 1861. There is no reason for D.C. to be its own state. Currently, the smallest state (by far) is Rhode Island at 1,214 square miles. D.C. is 68 square miles.

Comment: @reirab: If it's a package deal, i.e. go-into-state-and-be-split-up-immediately, it's not the same kind of precedent. Maryland would just be a facilitator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123352/discussion-between-reirab-and-einpoklum).