# What would it take for the District of Columbia to be made a state?

Tags: united-states, constitution, statehood, washington-dc, us-states

It seems the Biden administration [supports](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/sports/the-biden-administration-supports-making-washington-dc-the-51st-state/vi-BB1fRwJ8) the recognition of the District of Columbia as another US state. This raises the question of what will it take for this to happen?

Obviously, such a state would add 2 likely-Democratic-party senators, so Democrats would tend to support it and Republicans to oppose. On the other hand, such an addition would deprive the farther-right-wing Democratic-party senators like Manchin and Sinema from some of their leverage in the currently 50/50-split senate - so they (and maybe others?) have some motivation to oppose this, or abstain or be absent.

As for the procedure, is it like passing a law? If that's the case, it would be subject to a filibuster; and there will be the question of whether this can be included in a [budget reconciliation procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconciliation_(United_States_Congress)) or not.

Otherwise, if there's a different procedure - what kind of majorities are necessary? And how long is the procedure (ignoring arbitrary delays)?

**Note:** A separate [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43353/would-it-take-any-sort-of-amendment-to-make-dc-a-state?noredirect=1&lq=1) regards possible relevant changes to the constitution regarding this transition.

Comment: I think the duplicate addresses most of this.  A simple joint motion is sufficient (which can be filibustered and can't budget reconciliation). But this would leave several inconsistencies in the constitution (in particular amend 23) so it might be safer to proceed by the the approval of 3/4 of the several states.

Comment: @JamesK: Actually, it seems like Amendment 23 is the lesser issue - from my reading anyway - since the new state will no longer be a non-state district, and thus the amendment will not apply to it. Althoufgh, granted, there is definitely some interpretative [ijtihad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ijtihad) here.

Comment: @JamesK Fixing the 23rd amendment should be simple to do once it is made a state and you just need congress to vote for a new state.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of that question that is just asking about an amendment to the constitution while this is asking about the process about becoming a state which is different.

Comment: @JoeW: Yes, me neither. I mean, sure, there are some constitutional difficulties which the other question is about, but there is also a political challenge for the Biden administration which is what I'm more interested in. That being said - fixing constitutional amendments is not a simple thing to do...

Comment: I am sure removing an invalidated section after statehood won't get much pushback and the 23rd amendment was passed July 16, 1960 and ratified March 29, 1961 which shows things can move along quickly.

Comment: @JoeW: You're relying on the good-faith parliamentary conduct of the Republican contigent of the Senate... under Mitch McConnell... I must commend your optimism.

Comment: Read the Constitution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admission_to_the_Union

Comment: @HotLicks: "New States may be admitted by the Congress into this Union" - ok, but that clause doesn't say how. The Wikipedia article does partly answer the question; it doesn't say whether this is subject to filibuster. JamesK seems to address this point.

Answer (score 5):

As [Would it take any sort of amendment to make DC a state?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43353/would-it-take-any-sort-of-amendment-to-make-dc-a-state?noredirect=1&lq=1) states, it is like passing a law. In particular a Joint Resolution of Congress, (which might be filibustered by opponents in the Senate). These typically authorise statehood subject to the approval of a state constitution that is acceptable to Congress by referendum in the district or territory.

It would take extreme political manoeuvring to make this a budget resolution measure. This is certainly not what budget resolution was ever intended to be about.

Laws can get passed pretty quickly, but this one is likely to be controversial, and controversial laws take longer, if they get passed at all. There would need to be a state constitution to approve and probably a referendum, although this isn't strictly needed. Congress can admit new states with a republican form of government by law alone.

Depending on the precise nature of the bill, there may need to be a constitutional amendment. If (for example) the bill makes DC into a state, but convert the immediate area around the Capitol and the White House into a "micro-district", then you would probably want to remove the electoral college members from this micro-district, which would require an amendment (approval by congress and 3/4 of the states ratifying). This might not get much push-back, but would take some time to process.

Comment: It should be noted that congress passed a DC statehood bill for the second time and now it just needs to get past the filibuster in the senate. https://www.cnbc.com/2021/04/22/house-to-vote-on-dc-statehood-bill-that-faces-long-odds-in-the-senate.html

Comment: "then you would probably want to remove the electoral college members from this microdistrict" <- Well, they would, but that's not a precondition. Still, how many people live in that hypothetical micro-district?

Comment: If "it needs to get past the filibuster" then it hasn't passed Congress.  Congress consists of two houses.  (even though "congressperson" is generally taken to mean "representative" and not "senator") Senators are members of Congress, but they are not normally referred to or addressed as "Congresspeople".

Comment: When correcting my spelling (Thanks!)  take care not to introduce dialect changes.  I'm a British English speaker and writer and "manoeuvring" is the correct spelling in my dialect, even in an answer about American politics.

Comment: Since states receive federal subsidies, they might be able to finagle that into a justification for using budget reconciliation.